# Gridview in Android not showing the characters

Tags: android, android-gridview

I'm creating a Word Search game with 10x10 grids in a gridview.
Alphabets are not fully displayed in each cell.
Here is the [Screen shot of gridview with characters filled in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvhBY.png)

Code snippets are given below:

**MainActivity.java**

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
GridView gridView;

static final String[] numbers = new String[] {
        "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
        "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U",
        "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F",
        "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U",
        "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
        "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U",
        "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F",
        "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U",
        "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
        "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U",
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers);

    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    ((TextView) v).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

android:id="@+id/gridView1"
android:numColumns="10"
android:gravity="center"
android:columnWidth="50dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"

tools:context="in.viyanservices.wordsearch1.MainActivity">
</GridView>
```

I followed this tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/. He used     android:numColumns="auto_fit". I'm using     android:numColumns="10"

Your response would be appreciated! Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

Just change your xml property

```
android:stretchMode="spacingWidth"
```

Comment: android:stretchMode="spacingWidth" worked when I set the columnWidth="50dp". 

But, when columnWidth is set to "30dp", the same problem happens. The alphabets are not shown fully.

Comment: if you want to decrease column size than you have to  decrease size of textview inside gridview ... for that you have to use you custom textview...

Answer (score 0):

> Update your `GridView` XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context="in.viyanservices.wordsearch1.MainActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <GridView 
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="10"/> 
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: I want to see the entire grid in a single screen. your suggestion would make the users to scroll horizontally. right?

Comment: its not possible to show 10 column in single screen in small resolution devices.